# Can you recommend a good .NET web-based repository browser for SVN?

Tags: .net, asp.net, svn

We have an SVN repository running on a Windows server, and I want to link internal documentation, feature changes, bugs and so on to code changes.

We've found WebSVN to be amazingly slow - the repository is too large for it (I think).

The team using it is primarily coding in C#, and while some have experience with other languages I'd really like a tool anyone on the team can maintain.

Most of the tools I've seen are based on PHP, Java, Python, etc. All languages the team could learn, but I'd rather something that uses the skills we already have.

Can you recommend a good web-based repository browser for SVN, ideally one that uses ASP.NET, [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) and that runs on [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://warehouseapp.com

It's Mongrel/Ruby/MySQL stack (should work on Windows though)

> but I'm looking to avoid installing
>   MySQL and Ruby on the server.

I know (also using C# stack myself), but self-hosted web-based SVN client market is such a small niche that even offering in different language could be considered good enough. MySQL doesn't bite and installation of Ruby is pretty much x-copy command. I understand why you don't want to spoil your server with additional software though, but if are OK to host your SVN repositories with third-party, you get a nice web-based interface without maintenance hassles.

I'm using http://unfuddled.com (they also have some basic API to hook up on if needed).

> Not to promote reinventing the wheel,
>   but I originally wrote my own web SVN
>   browser by using the **svn log --xml**
>   command

This is actually good idea. I'm also parsing some XML formatted output during my automated build process, but creating our own full-blown SVN browser is kind of overkill because now you have to maintain not one primary project, but also the tool. But then again, we, programmers, love to create tools that will make working on our primary projects easier.

**ASP.NET SVN browser sounds like promising open-source idea, anybody willing to start work on it? I would contribute.**

Comment: I've written the beginnings of an ASP.NET SVN browser using the same framework ANKH uses. It was very slow at querying my wush.net SVN account so I built a bit of caching into it. It's not AJAX as yet and purely in prototype format, but would be happy to start something on google code.

Comment: unfortunately I've lost my interest in SVN since I wrote this last year. it's almost funny how things change in IT world so fast.

Answer (score 3):

Not to promote reinventing the wheel, but I originally wrote my own web SVN browser by using the

```
svn log --xml
```

command and then just an XML parser in whatever language i was using. I don't use .Net, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Warehouse](http://warehouseapp.com), as Lubos already pointed out, and it works very well. I looked at one point for a .NET version, but I was never able to find one. I was also at a point where I wanted to better myself as a programmer by learning a new language, and I ventured into learning Ruby and [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails). Now, I program in both .NET and Ruby. Anyway, that is how I ran into Warehouse.

I have Warehouse installed on a Linux machine running the Ubuntu server edition, [nginx](http://nginx.net/) for the HTTP server, and [mongrel cluster](http://mongrel.rubyforge.org/wiki/MongrelCluster). I never even tried to install it on Windows and am glad that I didn't.  Warehouse requires the svn-ruby bindings to work and this [poor guy](http://forum.activereload.net/forums/8/topics/452) found out the hard way.

Well, I know you are looking for a .NET application, but I thought I would give my two cents on Warehouse and I hope you don't dismiss it just because it doesn't run in .NET. I also wanted to inform you not to install Warehouse on Windows, if you did decide to give it a shot.

Comment: Warehouse code is now on https://github.com/entp/warehouse

Answer (score 1):

Is your Subversion repository hosted inside of Apache (rather than svnserve)? If so, and your needs are very simple, you can access the repository directly through a web browser. Just take the repository URL, plop it in the browser, and you'll see a very rudimentary web navigation interface (basically the built-in Apache folder browsing interface). It's not pretty, but it works for basic linking to repository files if that's all you need.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I thought that only let you browse the latest version. I want to show differences.

Do you know how to show file differences with the Visual SVN server?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily the answer to your question, but it seems like most other answers also mention related solutions, so I think this is worthwhile.

http://ifdefined.com/doc_bug_tracker_subversion.html

It's an open source project called BugTracker.NET.  It's primarily an issue tracker (one we use well here), but it does include Subversion integration with, among other things, the ability to view diffs.  We haven't implemented that piece but it looks fairly nice from the screen shots.

It's IIS/MSSQL based, so it's a Windows deployment-friendly solution.  I've found it to be solid, if a bit tricky to set up.

It's not a raw repository browser, but close and hits on some of the other qualities you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Not web-based but if your team is using TortoiseSVN there's a great repository browser there. Just right click on your local checkout and select TortoiseSVN / Repo-Browser.

Comment: That's great, but it's desktop based. I'm asking for web based.